Trying to set up an API Connection from local files to SharePoint with sharepy. I'm getting an "unknown authentication error" response
I'm trying to connect to Sharepoint using the sharepy extension for Python, however the authentication isn't working.
Every time I try to use the connect function, like so:
site_url= 'https://example.sharepoint.com/sites/sample/'
username = 'fake@generic.org'
password = 'Password3030'
sp = sharepy.connect(site_url, username, password)

It's come back with this: Screenshot of error message showing an "unknown authentication error"
I suspect it's a problem with not receiving the token properly, but it's unclear to me how this can be resolved, as it seems that it's an issue on the microsoft server's end. Has anyone had this issue? How might it be solved?
